# Elasticsearch Nested Query with Must and Must Not with same fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Sample data

```
poll_A:
{
  popular: [
    { domains: [ "google.com", "etsy.com", "amazon.com" ], rank: 1 },
    { domains: [ "google.com", "amazon.com" ], rank: 2 },
  ]
}

poll_B:
{
  popular: [
    { domains: [ "google.com", "etsy.com", "amazon.com" ], rank: 1 },
    { domains: [ "google.com", "etsy.com", "amazon.com" ], rank: 2 },
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create a query that will check if a domain only exists in rank 1. The following query is what I started with because it seemed right. However, it seems that the match query will check across every instance of the nested field regardless of which rank I want to check against.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "popular",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "popular.domains": "etsy.com"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "popular.rank": 1
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "popular.domains": "etsy.com"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "popular.rank": {
                  "gte": 2
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially I want to check that the domain matches in rank 1 but does not match with any other rank.

Answer (score 0):

I ended figuring out the right syntax to get what I needed. Here is what worked for me in case it helps anyone else:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "popular",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "popular.Domains": "etsy.com"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "popular.Rank": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "popular",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "popular.Domains": "etsy.com"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "popular.Rank": {
                        "gte": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query as below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "popular",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "popular.domains": "etsy.com"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "popular.rank": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "popular",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "popular.domains": "etsy.com"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "popular.rank" :{
                        "gte": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note the structure as how I've pushed the code for `must_not` in the outer `must` clause.

That way it would help you get the required solution.

Hope it helps!